# React create class confusion with extends Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I used to do React.createClass but since I heard it's faster with extends component and since I start to play with babel now, I would like to convert stateless legacy component with the newer style.

I have this

```
const Main = React.createClass({
   render(){
      return(<h1>my title</h1>)
   }
})
```

so what's the 'newer' syntax for above code?

is it like this?

```
const Main = () => { 
   render(){
       return(<h1>my title</h1>)
   }
}
```

Then when to use React.component?

```
class Main extends React.Components() {
   render(){ return(<h1>something</h1>}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React: when to use ES6 class based components vs. functional ES6 components?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36097965/react-when-to-use-es6-class-based-components-vs-functional-es6-components)

Comment: Your stateless component is incorrect and should be `const Main = (props) => <h1>my title</h1>`; There is no `render` function. The function itself is the render function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not performance difference between using

```
const Main = () => { 

       return(<h1>my title</h1>)

}
```

or

```
class Main extends React.Component {
   render(){ return(<h1>something</h1>}
}
```

given they receive the same props, however the react creators suggest that performance improvements will be made in future. So in short,

Use the first approach, which is a `functional component` approach when your component only takes in props and renders the result. However use the `ES6 class based` approach, when your React component has more functionality and handles states.

In your case you are just rendering the component so a functional component approach will be best suited for you

Answer (score 0):

Both of your example is correct. Just that the extends `Component` should be without `s` and need to `import React, { Component } from 'react';` at the top.

```
const Main = () => { 
    return(<h1>my title</h1>)
}
```

You generally want to use the above example when it is does not need any `lifecycle` methods. This are refer to as Pure component that will always behave the same when given the same `props`. It also does not keep `state`.

```
class Main extends React.Component() {
  componentWillMount() {
    console.log("I can be not pure");
  }

  render(){ return(<h1>something</h1>}
}
```

The above are `Component` that could manage `state` and use `lifecycle` methods.

Usually to decide what to use, I always start with a pure component. When continue developing, I discover that I have to use `state` or `lifecycle` methods, I would then turn it to a component.

Comment: A stateless component won't have a render function It would just be: `const Main = (props) => <h1>my title</h1>`. I think it's even invalid JS and wouldn't run.

Comment: Yes, you are right I didn't test it when answering. My bad. Updated it now