# React ES6 components using arrow functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-class

Very new to react, 
I have a class like:

```
export const Checkbox = ({ label, className }) => {
  ....
  .... 
  return(
    .............
    .............

  );             
}
```

In such a class how can I specify add a componentDidMount and componentWillReceiveProps?

**Edit:**

I have a layman's doubt, which is the correct way to create a wrapper react component for checkbox? functional component or by extending from Component? If I create a Checkbox wrapper component for others to use, will it be possible for them to connect to a store (say redux) from their pages?

Thanks,
Santhosh

Comment: You cannot. That's actually invalid syntax. You would want to replace render with return. To utilize lifcycle methods use must create a class which extends React.Component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

These are functional components and do not support React's lifecycle methods.

If you want to use React's lifecycle methods, you need a class that inherits from `React.Component`

See example below.

```
class Example extends React.Component {
    
   componentDidMount(){
     //code here
   }
    
}
```

[Here is a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36097965/react-when-to-use-es6-class-based-components-vs-functional-es6-components) explaining the differences and when to use functional over class components.

## **UPDATE from React 16.8**

Lifecycle methods can now be used with the introduction of [hooks](https://github.com/facebook/react/releases/tag/v16.8.0).

If you wished to implement `componentDidMount` you would use the `useEffect` hook and pass an empty array as the second argument. An example would look like as follows.

```
const Example = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // do stuff here
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: typo in source code - should be `extends React.Component`

Comment: @john_omalley well spotted! I should really go to sleep here!

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

If you want to use React's lifecycle methods, you need a class that inherits from React.Component.

```
export class Checkbox extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        ....
    }

    render() {
        const { label, className } = this.props;
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: @ I have a layman's doubt, which is the correct way to create a wrapper react component for checkbox? functional component or by extending from Component? If I create a Checkbox wrapper component for others to use, will it be possible for them to connect to a store (say redux) from their pages?

Comment: @kalladaYou can use either to create your own wrapper of a checkbox. Redux works with supplying props to a component, so any component that renders based on props will work.

Comment: @paul_fitzgerald I'm a bit confused why your answer, which has  literally copied the main sentence from my answer is now changed to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.  You should create a class that extends PureComponent or Component if you need lifecycle methods.