# Is it good practice to have a child with constructor and its own state in React JS? Or should props be used in this case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a child component that is getting rendered on App.js (parent) with its own state as it is not dependent on the parent state. Is this good practice? Or should props be used?

Comment: It depends on specific case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what the use of your child component is. If the component only uses a few props to render, there is no use for a class based component with its own state. If the component needs more functionality (states etc) you are better of using a class based component.

Also, if your component have a few child components which are dependent on their parent it could be appropriate using state.

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36097965/react-when-to-use-es6-class-based-components-vs-functional-es6-components) is relevant to what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

The React documentation describes the process of [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up) in which they suggest that indeed, as a general practice, state should be lifted up (e.g., into the parent) and given to children as props.