# React constructor(), componentDidmount with props variable

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

Where I can call the constructor() and componentDidmount event with below code:

```
export const Home = props => (props.isAuthenticated ? (
  <DashBoard {...props} />
) : (<Marketing {...props} />));
```

What is the meaning of the above code and how it's work?

Comment: Its a functional component. You can't call constructor in there. Either use hooks or handle condition on those respected components(eg DashBoard or Marketing one)

Comment: you may find your [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36097965/when-to-use-es6-class-based-react-components-vs-functional-es6-react-components)

Answer (score 2):

This is a functional component, correctly formatted is probably a little easier to read:

```
export const Home = props => (
  props.isAuthenticated ? ( 
    <DashBoard {...props} /> // if authenticated return and render Dashboard
  ) : (
    <Marketing {...props} /> // else return and render Marketing
  )
);
```

In functional components use the `useEffect` hook with an empty dependency array to achieve the equivalent of a class-based component's `componentDidMount`. Hooks are called on mount and whenever a variable in its dependency array are updated.

[effect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#effect-hook)

```
export const Home = props => {
  useEffect(() => console.log("I just mounted!", []); // empty so called once when the component is mounted

  return (
    props.isAuthenticated ? ( 
      <DashBoard {...props} /> // is authenticated return and render Dashboard
    ) : (
      <Marketing {...props} /> // else return and render Marketing
    )
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use react lifecycle hooks in a functional component. Refer to react documentation below for usage of lifecycle hooks, and to convert functional components to class components.

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentDidMount() {}

  render() {
    const { isAuthenticated } = this.props;
    return (
      <>
        {isAuthenticated ? <DashBoard {...this.props} /> : <Marketing {...this.props} />}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export const Home = props => (props.isAuthenticated ? (
  <DashBoard {...props} />
) : (<Marketing {...props} />));
```

**Details**

So the above code is a functional component, currently functional components can handle all the lifecycle methods that we use in class based components

So prev, before 16.8 of reactjs we can have state and life cycle methods in a functional components, It was only used for rendering the elements like as a presentational components. So at a point for complex applications we need to convert the functional components to class based components to handle a single state change

So this made the evolution of hooks, you can read more on the official docs of react js

So comming to your case if you need to call the method in componentDidMount, you can call as shown below

useEffect(() => {
  // your logic same as componentDidMount in class based components
}, [])

So the second argument is the dependencies for the useEffect to trigger

if you pass it as like this it will call every time

```
useEffect(() => {})
```

If you pass it as like this it will call whenever the passed variable changes from props or state

```
useEffect(() => {}, [data, userName])
```

I hope this will give a better understanding of the problem