# In Gatsby what is the difference in exteding component vs arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use gatsby with wordpress as a source.  It's been a fun process but I'm new to react and JS in general.

Can someone tell me the difference between these two methods?

```
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import React, { Component } from "react"

class StaticMenu extends Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to="/">home</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/blog">blog</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/page-list">pages</Link></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    )
  }
}

export default StaticMenu
```

and

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from "gatsby"

const WPMenu =() => (
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><Link to="/">home</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="/blog">blog</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="/page-list">pages</Link></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
);

export default WPMenu
```

or better yet...which I should use?

Comment: Well, one is class and one is arrow function. In the first one, you use state inside the class, in the second one you use hooks as state. I prefer functions, but you can use whatever you want.

Comment: Check out these resources: https://medium.com/@Zwenza/functional-vs-class-components-in-react-231e3fbd7108 , https://overreacted.io/how-are-function-components-different-from-classes/

Comment: @wlh your first resource is pre-hooks version, so it might mislead OP.

Comment: "Which should I use?" is primarily opinion-based, thus off-topic. As for the differences, it was already [asked and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36097965/1218980) multiple times.

Comment: @Mirakurun Perhaps, thought the article includes updates for hooks.

Comment: @wlh yes, but it says in 10 lines that you can't use state in function components, and only in one "now you can". Thus I said it MIGHT mislead OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are valid syntax for creating a component. Community is moving towards functional components(arrow functions included) after the introduction of *[Hooks Api](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)*

Previously, functional components were used just as presentational components without state and a functional component renders on each render of parent regardless of components props changed or not (before hooks, memo) and class based components were used as stateful components aka Containers (kindly don't fight over containers).

But now we have api like `memo` which allows us to use functional components which do not re-render on every render of parent unless props get changed so it provides shallow comparison of previous props and current props. You can also pass a second argument to add your custom logic to determine when do you want your component to re-render.

```
let Person = (props) => <div>{props.name}</div>;
Person = memo(Peron, someComparisonCallBackOrNothing);
```

After the introduction of React Hooks like `useState, useEffect, use*`, we can use functional components as stateful components

```
const Person = props => {
   const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
   const [person, setPerson] = useState({});
   const getPerson = async (id) => {
       const data = await axios.get(`/persons/${id}`);
       setPerson(data);
   }
   useEffect(() => {
      // Get user data from some api
      getPerson();
   }, [props.id]);  /// will be triggered on componentDidMount or if props.id changes
}
```