# Unexpected token, expected ";"

Tags: javascript, react-native

Can someone help me why I get the error of ==> Unexpected token, expected ";"

```
const AppRoot = () => {
  const [tabIndex, setTabIndex] = React.useState(1);
  const handleTabsChange = index => {
    setTabIndex(index);
  };
  this.state={
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    backgroundColor2: 'black',
    pressed: false,
  };
  changeColor(){
    if(!this.state.pressed){
       this.setState({ pressed: true,backgroundColor: 'red', backgroundColor2: 'black'});
    } else {
      this.setState({ pressed: false, backgroundColor: 'black' ,backgroundColor2: 'red'});
    }
  }
```

Comment: You're also missing the closing `}`but this may just be a copy paste error

Comment: From what I can see of your code ... AppRoot isn't closed ? ... Beside that why are you using useState AND this.state ? I'm not sur but if your component doesn't extends the React.class you won't be able to use this.state !

Comment: you using this in functional component.....

Comment: Please go through the documentation and check the difference between functional components and class components. There are many SO posts on this too: [When to use ES6 class based React components vs. functional ES6 React components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36097965)

Comment: Long story short, you are using the function component, and when you are using it along with Hooks you should not use `.SetState()`, instead use a set function in which you are getting a response from `useState()` hook (in your sample you should use `setTabIndex()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Since you are using the react hook, you should use React.useState for all states. (best practice)

So, instead of this.state={...}, you should use React.useState e.g.

```
const [backgroundColor, setBckgroundColor] = React.useState('black')
const [backgroundColor2, setBckgroundColor2] = React.useState('black')
const [pressed, setPressed] = React.useState(false)
```

or

```
const [myState, setMyState] = React.useState({
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    backgroundColor2: 'black',
    pressed: false,
})
```

2. You should use an arrow function.

```
const changeColor = () => {
    if(!this.state.pressed){
       this.setState({ pressed: true,backgroundColor: 'red', backgroundColor2: 'black'});
    } else {
      this.setState({ pressed: false, backgroundColor: 'black' ,backgroundColor2: 'red'});
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`changeColor` needs to be flaged as a function `function changeColor() {}` 
 or a variable `const changeColor = () => {}`