# React / Passing information to rebuild a list of item

Tags: reactjs

Hello

I have built an image gallery from a json file. Now the idea is to pick a color with  and if it matches one of the color associated in the json file, to rebuild a new list and refresh the page. (of course there is a proximity algorithm which is not the problem yet)

Here is my code for json file :

```js
{
    "images": [
        {
            "name": "1020.jpg",
            "palette": [
                "#b43f45",
                "#1c2c6c",
                "#e5c8c0",
                "#ab6257",
                "#313449",
                "#b1b5c1"
            ],
```

And the js

```js
import "./App.css";
import myjson from "./refs.json";
import PickColor from "./PickColor";

function App() {
  const images = myjson.images;

  return (
    <div>
      <PickColor />
      <div className="gallery">
        {images.map((index, i) => {
          return <img src={`./images/${index.name}`} key={i} alt="" />;
          <div className="colorBox">palette</div>
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am trying to understand the right methodology before going on

- Is it better to use a class or a function ?
- If App is a function, can Pickcolor be a class ?
- How can I pass information from PickColor.js to the tage div className="gallery"

I am a bit confuse about useState and state comprehension

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between react class component and react functional component is you can use react hooks only in functional component.

1. For your first question you can read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36097965)
2. For your second question the answer is yes. You can combine react class component and react functional component.
3. For your third question you can [lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). Instead of creating the state in child component you can create the state in parent component and pass the state and setter function using props.

Comment: I understand better. So it means when I pick a color in the PickColor Class, if I want to access this information in the function App I must use UseState in App.css ?

Comment: Yes, or you can use react context instead of prop drilling